# Address already in use... sockets in C

Tags: c++, linux, sockets

This question has been asked before, yet I just can't seem to come to grips with it as small details of all the questions ive ever seen throw me off...

I keep having issues where when I make a TCP socket server, the port becomes unusable for X ammount of time IF I establish a connection (if the connection is not established with the client, I can re-run the program after termination without issue). This is aparently somthing to do with a timeout that TCP requires before it will drop the connection.

I am using close(socketfd) on both the server and the client's socket with no prevail... Is there a way to make the socket IMMEDIATLY avaliable for use after successful termination (as in, close called on the fd) without having to wait what seems forever or restart the machine?

Comment: Which TCP socket lib do you use ? My guess is the TCP timeout can be adjustable to your needs.

Comment: I used linux's #include <sys/socket.h>....... I think my main question is how do i use  SO_REUSEADDR.. ive seen a heap of posts sayin to use it, but none saying how :\

Comment: basically : int optval = 1; setsockopt(yoursocket,SOL_SOCKET,SO_REUSEADDR,&optval,sizeof(optval)); more details can be found by carefully reading the [documentation](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setsockopt)

Comment: where do I put this though? anywhere?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the relevant socket option is called [`SO_REUSEADDR`](http://linux.die.net/man/7/socket). You use [`setsockopt()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setsockopt) to set socket options.

You should normally not close the server's main socket though, instead you should use [`accept()`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/setsockopt) to create per-client sockets, which can be closed when the client disconnects.

Comment: where do I place it? and do I use this: "setsockopt( SO_REUSEADDR);"

Answer (score 1):

The socket can linger in a TIME_WAIT state for a while after being closed. To be able to reuse a socket while in this state set `SO_REUSEADDR`