# Using C sockets: Address already in use

Tags: c, sockets

So the basic premise of my program is that I'm supposed to create a tcp session, direct traffic through it, and detect any connection losses. If the connection does break, I need to close the sockets and reopen them (using the same ports) in such a way that it will seem like the connection (almost) never died. It should also be noted that the two programs will be treated as proxies (data gets sent to them, if the connection breaks it gets stored until connection is fixed, then data is sent off).

I've done some research and gone ahead and used setsockopt() with the SO_REUSEADDR option to set the socket options so that I can reuse the address.

Here's the basic algorithm I do to detect a connection break using signals:

1. After initial setup of sockets, begin sending data
2. After x seconds, set a flag to false, which will prevent all other data from being sent
3. Send a single piece of data to let the other program know the connection is still open, reset timer to x seconds
4. If I receive same piece of data from the program, set the flag to true to continue sending
5. If I don't receive the data after x seconds, close the socket and attempt to reconnect

(step 5 is where I'm getting the error).

Essentially one program is a client(on one VM) and one program is a server(on another VM), each sending and receiving data to/from each other and to/from another program on each VM.

My question is: Given that I'm still getting this error after setting the socket options, why am I not allowed to re-bind the address when a connection has been detected?

The server is the one complaining when a disconnect is detected (I close the socket, open a new one, set the option, and attempt to bind the port with the same information).

One other thing of note is the way I'm receiving the data from the sockets. If I have a socket open, I'm basically reading it by doing the following:

```
while((x = recv(socket, buff, 1, 0)>=0){

    //add to buffer
    // send out to other program if connection is alive
}
```

Since I'm using the timer to close/reopen the socket, and this is in a different thread, will this prevent the socket from closing?

Comment: I think you could look at those answers to try to solve your problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15788007/address-already-in-use-sockets-in-c

Comment: That loop condition should be `> 0`, not `>= 0`. You are looping at EOS.

Comment: @TomásBadan I actually saw that post earlier, and I tried implementing the setsockopt() call, but like I said, I still get the error.

Comment: @EJP Thanks, I forgot I hadn't changed that back!

Comment: You say the _server_ is the one complaining?  Why are you needing to re-open a socket on the server?  When a disconnect occurs, wouldn't the server just need to clean up the dead socket and then call accept(listening_socket, ...), while the client reconnects?

Answer (score 3):

`SO_REUSEADDR` only allows *limited* reuse of ports.  Specifically, it does not allow reuse of a port that some other socket is currently actively listening for incoming connections on.

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be an epidemic here of people calling `bind()` and then `setsockopt()` and wondering why the `setsockopt()` doesn't fix an error that had already happened on `bind()`.

You have to call `setsockopt()` *first.*

But I don't understand your problem. Why do you think you need to use the same ports? Why are you setting a flag preventing you from sending data? You don't need any of this. Just handle the errors on `send()` when and if they arise, creating a new connection when necessary. Don't try to out-think TCP. Many have tried, few if any have succeeded.

Comment: Sorry, I guess I didn't specify this. I AM calling setsockopt() before actually binding the socket. When creating the socket, the process is literally call socket(...), pass that return in to setsockopt(...), then bind the socket using bind(...). Reconnecting is just the same process, except I close the socket first. Using the same port is just one of the specifications of the program, so I can't get around that.

Comment: You're going to have to 'get around' it, because it's impossible, as per @ChrisDodd's answer. If you close a connection, its local port will be in TIME_WAIT state at best, and cannot be reused for two minutes. The whole thing is fundamentally misconceived, and you can tell them we said so. Send the specification back where it came from.